# Can't access @Viewbag properties after using statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The view is no longer accessing the @ViewBag after the @using(html.BeginForm)statement, and I don't know why.  I get an error "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context". Why is that?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
@{ Layout = null; }

@model IEnumerable<ReportViewModel>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="StyleSheets/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/StyleSheets/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/StyleSheets/css" />


    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Js/utills.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Js/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Js/rt.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>@ViewBag.title</title>


</head>
<body>

    @*@if ((ViewBag.site != "Sites" && ViewBag.site != null) || ViewBag.site != "PrintThis")
        {*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ReportForm" }))
        {
            if (@ViewBag.print != "PrintReport")
            {
            <div class="im-row im-padding-4 im-padding-top-16" id="Header" style="width: 100%;">

                <div class="im-container" style="width: 95%;">

                    <div class="im-col--3">
                        @Html.DropDownList(
                                 "OrderSelector",
                                 new SelectList(new[]
                                 {
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "L", Value = @Url.Action("Pdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = @ViewData["SCode"], site = @ViewBag.site, team = @ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "L"})},
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "R", Value = @Url.Action("Pdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = @ViewData["SCode"], site = @ViewBag.site, team = @ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "R"})},
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "D", Value = @Url.Action("Pdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = @ViewData["SCode"], site = @ViewBag.site, team = @ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "D"})},
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "T", Value = @Url.Action("tPdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = @ViewData["SCode"], site = @ViewBag.site, team = @ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "T"})},
                                 }, "Value", "Text"),
                                 new { id = "OrderSelector", @class = "sortOrder", onchange = "CallChangeFunc(this.value)" }
                                 )
                        <input id="SCode" type="hidden" value="@ViewData["SCode"]" />
                        <input id="SelectedSort" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.sortOrder" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="im-col--5" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <span>(to change your default sort preference, click on the 'Settings' tab)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="im-col--2">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", "Report", new { site = @ViewBag.site, team = @ViewBag.team, sortOrder = @ViewBag.sortOrder }, new { @class = "im-btn im-btn--primary im-btn--sm printBtn", id = "PrintPdf" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="im-row im-padding-4  im-col--12" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="im-container">
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
    <div class="im-container Report im-no-padding-left" style="width: 95%;" id="Report">
        <div class="im-row title">
            <div class="im-col--6 im-no-padding-left">
                <p class="im-text--extra-bold-weight inline">
                    CC
                </p>
                <p class="inline">
                    - @ViewBag.status, @ViewBag.site, @ViewBag.team, @ViewBag.user
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="im-col--6">
                <p class="im-text--extra-bold-weight inline">
                    @{ string[] currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("g").Split(' ');}
                    @currentDate[0] at @currentDate[1]
                </p>
                <p class="im-float--right im-text--color-grey im-text--extra-bold-weight inline">
                    @Model.Count() Rat(s)
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: which line are trying to add Viewbag

Comment: @hasan - ViewBag.status, ViewBag.site, ViewBag.team, ViewBag.user is the line that I'm trying to access it

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `@` character in your `if` statement. Because `@` is used to specify the C# code in razor. But if you start a C# code like `if` statement, you should not use the `@` character again. Like this:

```
if (ViewBag.print != "PrintReport")
{
...

}
```

But if your is statement nested in your HTML codes, you should start `if` statement with `@`. For example:

```
<div class="im-container" style="width: 95%;">
     @if(ViewBag.print != "PrintReport")
     {
       ...
     }
     <div class="im-col--3">
     </div>
</div>
```

> The view is no longer accessing the @ViewBag after the
>   @using(html.BeginForm)statement, and I don't know why.

Because you just used a C# code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ReportForm" }))
{
if (ViewBag.print != "PrintReport")
        {
```

And you didn't add a HTML code now. So, it percieves that you are using C# code. But if you start to add HTML codes, it realises the HTML code and after that you should add `@` before adding new C# codes.

So you don't have to use `@` in your C# statements but you have to use it where your C# codes nested in HTML codes. Like this:

```
<p class="inline">
     - @ViewBag.status, @ViewBag.site, @ViewBag.team, @ViewBag.user
</p>
```

Finally, for your code sample, you should change it like that:

```
<body>
    @*@if ((ViewBag.site != "Sites" && ViewBag.site != null) || ViewBag.site != "PrintThis")
        {*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ReportForm" }))
    {
        if (@ViewBag.print != "PrintReport")
        {
            <div class="im-row im-padding-4 im-padding-top-16" id="Header" style="width: 100%;">

                <div class="im-container" style="width: 95%;">

                    <div class="im-col--3">
                        @Html.DropDownList(
                                 "OrderSelector",
                                 new SelectList(new[]
                                 {
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "L", Value = Url.Action("Pdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = ViewData["SCode"], site = ViewBag.site, team = ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "L"})},
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "R", Value = Url.Action("Pdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = ViewData["SCode"], site = ViewBag.site, team = ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "R"})},
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "D", Value = Url.Action("Pdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = ViewData["SCode"], site = ViewBag.site, team = ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "D"})},
                                     new SelectListItem {Text = "T", Value = Url.Action("tPdf", "Report/", new {SecurityCode = ViewData["SCode"], site = ViewBag.site, team = ViewBag.team, sortOrder = "T"})},
                                 }, "Value", "Text"),
                                 new { id = "OrderSelector", @class = "sortOrder", onchange = "CallChangeFunc(this.value)" }
                                 )
                        <input id="SCode" type="hidden" value="@ViewData["SCode"]" />
                        <input id="SelectedSort" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.sortOrder" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="im-col--5" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <span>(to change your default sort preference, click on the 'Settings' tab)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="im-col--2">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", "Report", new { site = ViewBag.site, team = ViewBag.team, sortOrder = ViewBag.sortOrder }, new { @class = "im-btn im-btn--primary im-btn--sm printBtn", id = "PrintPdf" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="im-row im-padding-4  im-col--12" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="im-container">
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
    <div class="im-container Report im-no-padding-left" style="width: 95%;" id="Report">
        <div class="im-row title">
            <div class="im-col--6 im-no-padding-left">
                <p class="im-text--extra-bold-weight inline">
                    CC
                </p>
                <p class="inline">
                    - @ViewBag.status, @ViewBag.site, @ViewBag.team, @ViewBag.user
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="im-col--6">
                <p class="im-text--extra-bold-weight inline">
                    @{ string[] currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("g").Split(' ');}
                    @currentDate[0] at @currentDate[1]
                </p>
                <p class="im-float--right im-text--color-grey im-text--extra-bold-weight inline">
                    @Model.Count() Rat(s)
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <p class="inline">
                    - ViewBag.status, ViewBag.site, ViewBag.team, ViewBag.user
                </p>

Comment: ^ Why can't I access this though?

Comment: I updated the answer. You should use "@"  at outside of C# statements to describe that you are starting to use C# codes in Razor.